# Why does Swift hang when I print a string that was converted from a byte array?

Tags: ios, swift

I receive bytes from socket using: .read
Bytes contain "my message" and nothing else.  No termination.
I convert to string.  Should be "my message".
Print string and it displays "my message" then hangs.
(I don't know how Swift terminates strings.  In C, I'd just pop 0 onto the end of the bytes.)

```
var latest_hub_bytes = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: 1024)

received_byte_count = (inputStream?.read( &latest_hub_bytes,            
                                        maxLength: HUB_TO_CLIENT_SIZE_BYTES ))!  

var message_from_hub: String = String(  bytes: latest_hub_bytes, 
                                        encoding: .utf8 )!

print("     message_from_hub:", message_from_hub )
print("next line")
```

OUTPUT...
message_from_hub: my message(lldb)

<<<  missing "next line". >>>

Comment: Did you have a chance to check if my suggestion helped?

Answer (score 1):

```
String(bytes: latest_hub_bytes, encoding: .utf8)
```

convert the entire array to a string. You can use

```
String(bytes: latest_hub_bytes[..<received_byte_count], encoding: .utf8 )
```

instead, which converts only the part (“slice”) of the array which has been filled by the read operation. But note that this still requires a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.